# What's the bzr command to revert

Tags: bazaar, revert

Easy question.

I have downloaded gnome-do and I'm starting to learn about it.

By mistake I have removed a file and now I want to update it with the latest version.

What'st the bzr command to do that?

I've tried bzr update but it always says I'm up to date :(

The deleted file looks like an uncommited change. What's the bzr option to rollback that change?  I have tried revert, but only removes the previous version of the whole project and didn't recover my deleted file :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bzr revert <file>
```

This will bring the file back.